# Random blocks using JavaFX

Tags: random, javafx

How to get random blocks(black & white) in board using JavaFX?

using:

```
Random ran = new Random()
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a method, you can adapt it to your need :

```
private void ColoreBlock(Pane p){

    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNum = random.nextInt((1 - 0) + 1) + 0; // range (1-0) white/black

    switch (randomNum) {
    case 0:    
    p.setStyle("-fx-background-color:white;");  // -fx-fill for shape
    break;
    case 1: 
    p.setStyle("-fx-background-color:black;");  // -fx-fill for shape   
    break;
    }

}
```